# Strange SVN behavior (missing files) when using depth immediates followed by depth infinity

Tags: svn

Alright, I have this strange one to pick your brains about.

---

- Repository:

  - Revision 0: empty
  - Revision 1: `dir1/f1.txt`
  - Revision 2: `dir1/f1.txt`, `dir1/f2.txt`, `dir2/f3.txt`

Your typical, right?

---

Now for the strangeness. I get this with SVN 1.6.5 and 1.6.13 alike. I'm not going to be able to upgrade to try to get rid of this. I'm running these commands in the working copy root.

- Commands

  1. `svn update -r1` - Update to revision 1 is successful, working copy looks good.
  2. `svn update --depth immediates` - All good, `dir2` gets created and is empty, no other changes.
  3. `svn update dir1 --set-depth infinity` - SVN says OK, but `dir1/f2.txt` just won't pop up in my working copy.
  4. `svn update` - just cause I'm getting anxious - nothing, `dir1/f2.txt` still wont pop up.
  5. `svn update -r1` - Error: `dir1/f2.txt` is not under version control (WHOA?)
  6. `svn update` - Now I get `dir1/f2.txt` in.

If anyone knows why `dir1/f2.txt` refuses to appear when I run step 3 and what, if anything, I am doing wrong, please do share.

Comment: You've found a bug. Report it and the steps you took to Apache's Subversion project. I followed your steps, and got the same thing. The only way around this is to update to revision 1 and then back to revision 2.

Comment: @DavidW: done, sent e-mail to the dev mailing list, as per their bug submission guidelines.

Comment: They confirm the bug but report that it is fixed in 1.7 and 1.8. I guess that means an upgrade is the way to go.

Comment: Do note that updating to revision 1 and then revision 2 can be problematic in its own right - files can end up in the `unversioned` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been confirmed a bug in SVN 1.6. The resolution is to upgrade to SVN 1.7 or SVN 1.8.

From the horse's mouth (the SVN dev list):

> On Thu, Aug 8, 2013 at 1:34 PM, Philip Martin
>    wrote:
>
> ```
> svnadmin create repo
> svnmucc -mm -U file://`pwd`/repo mkdir D1 put repo/format D1/f1
> svnmucc -mm -U file://`pwd`/repo put D1/f2 mkdir D2 put repo/format D2/f3
> svn co file://`pwd`/repo@1 wc
> svn up --depth immediates wc
> svn up --set-depth infinity wc/D1
> svn st -v wc
> ```
>
> With 1.7 and 1.8 the status shows
>
> ```
>              2        2 pm           wc
>              2        2 pm           wc/D1
>              2        1 pm           wc/D1/f1
>              2        2 pm           wc/D1/f2
>              2        2 pm           wc/D2
> ```
>
> With 1.6 the status shows
>
> ```
>              2        2 pm           wc
>              2        2 pm           wc/D2
>              2        2 pm           wc/D1
>              2        1 pm           wc/D1/f1
> ```
>
> So this is a bug in 1.6 that is fixed in 1.7 and 1.8.
>
> -- Philip Martin | Subversion Committer WANdisco | Non-Stop Data